# Change the Rendering in IE9 with Stylesheets

Tags: javascript, css, html, internet-explorer-9

is there a way to disable the rendering in IE9? Can we do it using stylesheet changes?
or some meta character on the webpage maybe?

thanks

**EDIT** here is a sample

in Chrome

[image]

and in IE9

[image]

i want the page to look as displayed in Chrome. Is there any way i can get that effect in IE9?

Comment: What did you mean with 'disable the rendering' ?

Comment: Did you try conditional html comments? (google it maybe)

Comment: i tried <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />

Comment: but that does not have any effect

Answer (score 1):

You could add a specific stylesheet which will be only loaded in **IE9** using IE **conditional comments**.
In this stylesheet you should add whatever you need to fix the rendering issues.

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<link href="stylesheets/ie9.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/internet-explorer-conditional-comments/) is more info about conditional comments and how it works.

Comment: thanks ! but i dont think the problem is in the css. the problem is that the two browsers are rendering the same information differently. so, although i have the same font size,style and weight it is displayed differently in ie9. even if i change the font attributes, the text still appears as a bit smudgy.

Comment: Your css is not the problem but you need to use css to fix the differences because each browser has its own default rules. You also can try using normalize (http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to reset those rules. Anyway without the code is hard to detect the issue. A fiddle with your code will help a lot.